# Angular 2 display Array in array

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

If I have this array :

```
array = [
{
  img: [
        {0: 'http://hairsalonfurniture.eu/wp-uploads/750x480_how-to-create-a-nice-hair-salon-s-reception-gjzd.jpg',},
        {1: 'http://hairsalonfurniture.eu/wp-uploads/750x480_how-to-create-a-nice-hair-salon-s-reception-gjzd.jpg',},
      ],
}

{
  img: [
        {0: 'http://hairsalonfurniture.eu/wp-uploads/750x480_how-to-create-a-nice-hair-salon-s-reception-gjzd.jpg',},
        {1: 'http://hairsalonfurniture.eu/wp-uploads/750x480_how-to-create-a-nice-hair-salon-s-reception-gjzd.jpg',},
      ],
}
]
```

How do I display it in HTML ? I know how to display one img if it was img : 'url' it would look like this ;

```
this.imgs = this.myprovider.getArray();
```

HTML :

```
<div ngfor="let item of imgs">{{item.img}}</div>
```

Comment: I wrote it by myself in a provider, so I am not sure if its valid, 0 errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your key in the array of `img` objects is a number starting at 0, you can just use the loop index to access the value:

```
<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let item of array">
    <ul>
      <li *ngFor="let image of item.img; let i = index">
        <img src="{{ image[i] }}" />
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Stack Blitz doesn't want to load the image URLs for some reason, but as you can see from the output, the HTML is correct: https://stackblitz.com/edit/nested-array-example

Comment: Cannot find a differ supporting object 'https://img.clipartxtras.com/7b4e3eec00b32e41310877ce87f1126a_living-room-niceving-room-ideas-with-blue-coloursnice-colours-nice-drawing-room-pictures_1920-1200.jpeg' of type 'string'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays

Comment: Did you look at the StackBlitz example? it uses your sample data. You can only bind ngFor to a value that supports iteration (looping). If the data you're actually using doesn't match your question, you need to update your question.

Comment: Btw, your example data is missing a comma in between the `array` objects, which is fixed in the example.

Comment: Its same as question , i have 2 urls  in array.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
<div ngfor="let item of imgs">{{item.img.toString()}}</div>
```

or

```
<div ngfor="let item of imgs">
    <div ngfor="let img of item.img">{{img}}</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate twice in nested manner -

```
<ng-container ngfor="let childImages of imgs">
    <div ngfor="let item of childImages">{{item.img}}</div>
<ng-container>
```

> Note : You should use  instead of any other html element otherwise it will distort html look & feel.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div *ngFor="let item of imgs">
    <div *ngFor="let img of item.img; let i=index;">{{img[i]}}</div>
</div>
```

Comment: ',' is missing inside object array.